# WIFI Direct not working on Brother printer DCP-T150W on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, printer, wifi-configuration, brother-printer

When I pair my Windows 10 laptop to my Brother printer via WIFI Direct, it connects successfully, however, on the Settings app, it shows "Driver is unavailable" under the printer and it doesn't show up as an option when I try to print a document. It doesn't show up on my Device Manager as well.

[image]

However, I can connect via WIFI Direct using my Android phone and print just fine though. I can also print on my laptop if I connect it via USB cable but I would rather use WIFI Direct for more flexibility.

I've already installed the full software suite from Brother's website but it it still shows "Driver is unavailable". Maybe I have to install something more specific that I'm missing?

Comment: Reboot your system the message about the driver not being available will be resolved

Comment: I already tried it, the message is still there, I tested it on two laptops both running Windows 10, they both had the same problem

Comment: When I had this problem rebooting my machine solved the problem but others have suggested also rebooting the printer might be required

Comment: I would also suggest connecting directly via USB to make sure the driver itself is working.. then unplug and narrow down the WIFI connection instance.  I did that just a couple of days ago with my wife's machine.  It at least lets you be sure of where the problem lies.

Comment: @Ramhound I have restarted the printer numerous times since pairing it with my laptop, still no dice.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas That was how I set up the device to begin with, by connecting via USB to configure the network connection. It works fine on Android, only Windows has a problem somehow.